# Why does my conditional SUM not work?

Tags: mac, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I am Using Excel 2011 for Mac and am having a hard time figuring out a way to return some data that I need.

I have a sheet with a table, column D is "Type" and column H has numbers. I want one cell to show to total of values in Column H given that the Type is "Status Update". I took a shot with

```
=IF('Key metrics'!D3:D31="Status Update",SUM('Key metrics'!H3:H31),0)
```

but that didn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the Mac version, but I imagine it's similar to PC version. If so, you can use the sumif function like this:-

```
=SUMIF(D3:D31,"Status Update",H3:H31)
```

If you have further conditions to use, then you could look into using array formulas to create products of booleans like this:

```
{=SUM((D3:D31="Status Update")*(H3:H31))}
```

On a PC you have to enter the array formula by pressing Ctrl-Shift Enter. Not sure of the key equivalent on Mac but I'm sure there is one...

Comment: Yes that worked. I totally forgot about SUMIF, a bit rusty. Thanks!